# get thread ID or name in python 2.6

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to get thread ID or name in python 2.6 I follow examples but I get errors
 like 
global name 'currentThread' is not defined
global name 'current_thread' is not defined

(I tried both currentThread and current_thread)

Here is my code :

```
vim f3Q.py
  1 import Queue
  2 from threading import Thread
  3
  4 def do_work(item):
  5         try:
  6                 print current_thread().getName()
  7
  8
  9         except Exception as details:
 10                 print details
 11                 pass
 12         print item*2
 13
 14 def worker():
 15         while True:
 16                 item=q.get()
 17                 do_work(item)
 18                 q.task_done()
 19
 20 q=Queue.Queue()
 21 l=[13,26,77,99,101,4003]
 22 for item in l:
 23         q.put(item)
 24
 25
 26 for i in range (4):
 27         t=Thread(target=worker,name="child"+str(i))
 28         t.daemon=True
 29         t.start()
 30
 31
 32 q.join()
 33
```

UPDATE:
I fixed the error by the hint Mata gave
I should have imported current_thread() too.

```
from threading import Thread,current_thread
```

Comment: Spelling counts. `currenThread` is not the same thing as `currentThread`, and `curren_thread` is not the same thing as `current_thread`. So, even after you fix the error that mata found, it still won't work.

Comment: Also, that is not the error you'd get from the code you showed. You'd get `NameError: name 'threading' is not defined`. You're not using `currentThread` as a global name, you're using it as a member of a namespace that doesn't exist, so you can't possibly get an error about not finding it as a global name.

Comment: oh sorry the typos was just for here I wrote that part in the question myself...had deleted it in the code in the last momemnt

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You haven't imported `threading`, only `Thread`.

Either import `threading`, or import `current_thread` directly:

```
1 import Queue
2 from threading import Thread, current_thread
3
4 def do_work(item):
5         try:
6                 print current_thread()
```

Comment: when I say "import threading" I get the
NameError: name 'Thread' is not defined

Comment: `import threading` imports the module -> reference Thread as `threading.Thread`. `from threading import Thread` imports only Thread -> reference as `Thread`. Both options are valid, just slightly different implications.

Comment: by the way the output of my code above is child0 for all the threads, here is the output of my program :
child0
26
child0
52
child0
154
child0
198
child0
202
child0
8006

why it is not child0 to child3 ?

Comment: I found the answer, my list was too small all of them was consumed by the first thread.

Answer (score 6):

This will work

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread

    def do_work(item):
       print current_thread().name
```

Comment: The .name attribute definitely worked, but I only had to call `current_thread().name`, not `threading.current_thread().name` when the module is imported in the manner in which it is.